# bibtex + natbib + APA syntax confusion

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

my code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}


\begin{document}


It is particularly notable for its flexibility, its
superb hyphenation, and its ability to choose aesthetically satisfyingline\citep{Wel03}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

my bib file is :

```
@Book{Tho05,
author = "Thomas F. O'Brien and Tilak V. Bommaraju and Fumio Hine",
title = {Handbook of Chlor-Alkali Technology Volume I: Fundamentals},
publisher = {Springer Science+Business Media Inc.},
year = {2005},
address = {233 Spring Street, New York, NY 10013,
USA},
}
```

it compiles to:

[image]

in  the natbib documentation it says that \citep{key} results to:

[image]

I wanted to have that (author et. al, year) format just like the one in the documentation. What \cite would I need to type in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired authoryear citation style with round parentheses, you need to change the instruction

```
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
```

to

```
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
```

Be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes. You'll get the following look:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article} % changed from 'report' to 'article' for this MWE
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents*}{Bibliography.bib} % make this a self-contained MWE
@Book{Tho05,
  author = "Thomas F. O'Brien and Tilak V. Bommaraju and Fumio Hine",
  title = {Handbook of Chlor-Alkali Technology Volume I: Fundamentals},
  publisher = {Springer Science$+$Business Media Inc.},
  year = {2005},
  address = {233 Spring Street, New York, NY 10013, USA},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citep{Tho05}

\citet{Tho05}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can i ask you a question? what could be the problem of my bib file i keep on receiving this error message: ! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

Comment: @RicardoVelozJr - Barring some other, so far undiscovered syntax error(s) in the code, the message is almost certainly caused by material in the aux file(s) that's left over from a previous compilation run. Blowing away all aux files before recompiling should get rid of the message, as should -- assuming, naturally, that there are no other syntax and content errors -- simply running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more: the first time LaTeX pauses with the error message, simply hit return to make it continue, and the supposed error will get resolved.

Comment: I removed all entries that are URLs and the problem disappeared. do you know how to add those entries back that is in a way syntax compliant?